# jquery load() (simple implementation doesn't work)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I tried implementing the simple first example from w3 schools but for some reason text file is not loading.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

It seems really simple. Press a button and the load file replaces the div but its not working. Any help would be much appreciated thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

    <button>Get External Content</button>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#div1").load("load_file.txt");
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The load_file.txt contains the following, just as the website contains.

```
<h2>jQuery and AJAX is FUN!!!</h2>
<p id="p1">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Start with opening the console (F12) and check for errors ?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine on my localhost. Check for file permissions issues and make sure that your load_file.txt is in root directory (or wherever your page that's trying to load it is located).

Comment: You should check file permissions of `load_file.txt`. Also make sure that `load_file.txt` is in the same directory as your main website (the root directory). And as you're loading HTML, you may want to try using a HTML file (`load_file.html`) instead of a `.txt` file.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/MaxGittelman/Documents/HTML/load_file.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I added changed the .txt to .html and I get the error above?

Comment: @Max Is browser chrome ?

Comment: yes the browser is chrome